# In Python what is it called when you see the output of a variable without printing it?

Tags: python

In Python you can see the value of a variable without printing it, like:

```
>>> a = 'hello world'
>>> a
hello world
```

This is different from printing `print(a)`, yet I'm still able to see a similar output. What it the technical term for this type of variable printing?

As an example of the difference, below shows how a Jupyter Notebook prints a dataframe for both types of printing:

[image]

Comment: The returned value.

Comment: It's just the behavior of the interactive interpreter; the result of any expression is written to standard output. Nothing similar happens when you run a script outside of the interactive interpreter.

Comment: in an interactive interpreter, the REPL, you get essentially `print(repr(whatever))`, it's just printing, that is what a REPL is, a read, evaluate, **print**, loop

Comment: This isn't restricted to variables; type *any* expression at the prompt, and its value is printed to standard output. (The exception being an expression that evaluates to `None`; in that case, nothing is shown.)

Comment: @James, for something like `print(a)` I would say "I **print** the variable a". For typing `a` by itself would it be correct to say "I **return** the variable a"? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

You're executing code in a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop); the P stands for "print".

It's being implicitly printed by the console.

Comment: For `print(a)` I would say "I **print** the variable a". For typing `a` by itself would it be correct to say "I **implicitly print** the variable a"? Or something else? Is there Python documentation that discusses this?

Comment: @NicScozzaro I can't say honestly that I've ever differentiated between whether an expression was explicitly or implicitly printed. It rarely (if ever?) matters. I'd just say "a was printed out".

Comment: It matters to me because for example, if you print a dataframe vs implicitly print a dataframe in Jupyter Notebook you get different results. The latter is nicely printed as a table. I'm just looking for the correct term to refer to this, since it's not printing.

Comment: @NicScozzaro Ah, that would likely be a difference in whether or not the object's `__repr__` method was called. Your console might not properly call `__repr__` if it's printing out differently. That method defines how objects are printed nicely.

Comment: @NicScozzaro Actually, looking at your output, Jupyter seems to have a built-in special case for `Dataframe`s. That's not something that can be achieved via normal Python. When you call `print`, it `repr` gets called on the Dataframe first, which prevents your console from doing its own formatting.

Comment: `print` calls `__str__`, not `__repr__`.

Comment: Not sure what it's called, but the function `IPython.display.display` can be used to display a dataframe/etc. in Jupyter.

Answer (score 4):

It's not Python but the Python shell's (IDLE) behavior you're seeing. The way it's built, it prints the type or value of the item you specify. The actual Python would be to have this code inside a `.py` file:

```
a = 'hello world'
a
```

and you do `python test.py` then you'd see nothing, because the value returned by `a` would be silently discarded. The cli works as if there's an implicit `print()` statement there.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing if the `repr` of the last **expression** returned by the interpreter to the global namespace in interactive mode.  This is fundamentally different from the a **print** output, although they do go to the same stream.

For simple objects such as integer they look the same.

```py
>>> x = 1
>>> print(x)
1
>>> x
1
```

The difference is that `print` send the string representation of the object to the STDOUT.  Inputting a variable and hitting enter shows you the `repr` of the object.  To me the big difference is that the later can be easily captured by adding an assignment to the expression, i.e. `y = x`.  While the `print` output is more complicated to capture.

That is why I use the phrase "returns the value for x" or "returns x".  This indicates that if you wanted to capture the return as another variable, you could.

Here is a short example to show the difference between print and repr.

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'<Foo at 0x{id(self):x}>'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'Foo-object'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(f)
Foo-object
>>> f
<Foo at 0x17416af3c18>
```

Comment: Interesting. From the documentation,  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__, `repr` is the "official" string representation while `str` is the "informal" string representation. Your answer seems the most correct to me, but I'm still not clear what terminology to use to refer to one vs the other succinctly though.