# Is the setting of the vs_code wrong?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use python in visual studio code and, I wrote the code:

```
list_a = [10, 20, 30]
list_a
```

Running, I expected:

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

But, in visual studio code, not working.

This code is working:

```
print(list_a)
[10, 20, 30]
```

What's the problem??

Comment: When you just type a variable like `list_a` and it happens to display, that is typically in a REPL interpreter like IDLE. In VSCode unless you're running in an interactive interpreter that line will not print anything. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895060/in-python-what-is-it-called-when-you-see-the-output-of-a-variable-without-printi)

Comment: is this in a terminal or a python script?

Answer (score 0):

The first code was probably in a REPL or something like IDLE, where you get instant returning, without having to use print. VSCode is what you call a "text editor", where it doesn't provide instant feedback without using `print`. Instead, text editors (and their bigger brothers, IDEs) are much more suited to professional development, where you have a butt-ton of code with a butt-ton of files. And in this context, VSCode blows everyone else out the water.

If you still want a REPL, there are quite a few in the Marketplace, which you can get as extensions.